# C++ - const keyword in methods and overload

Tags: c++, overloading

for which reason this program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {
public:
  Base() { cout << "Costruttore Base" << endl; }
  virtual void foo(int) { cout << "Base::foo(int)" << endl; }
  virtual void bar(int) { cout << "Base::bar(int)" << endl; }
  virtual void bar(double) { cout << "Base::bar(double)" << endl; }
  virtual ~Base() { cout << "Distruttore Base" << endl; }
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived() { cout << "Costruttore Derived" << endl; }
  void foo(int) { cout << "Derived::foo(int)" << endl; }
  void bar(int) const { cout << "Derived::bar(int)" << endl; }
  void bar(double) const { cout << "Derived::bar(double) const" << endl; }
  ~Derived() { cout << "Distruttore Derived" << endl; }
};
int main() {
  Derived derived;
  Base base;
  Base& base_ref = base;
  Base* base_ptr = &derived;
  Derived* derived_ptr = &derived;
  cout << "=== 1 ===" << endl;
  base_ptr->foo(12.0);
  base_ref.foo(7);
  base_ptr->bar(1.0);
  derived_ptr->bar(1.0);
  derived.bar(2);
  return 0;
}
```

In the call `base_ptr->bar(1.0);` is called `Base::bar(double)`, instead in the `derived_ptr->bar(1.0);` is called `Derived::bar(double) const`.

I understood that is about the `const` keyword, but I don't understand why the compiler is choosing different overloaded functions.

If I remove the `const` keyword, everything is working as expected, calling in both cases the `Derived::bar`

Comment: Use the `override` keyword, and the compiler will tell you that you didn't override the base function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're not really overriding the function bar(). You are defining a **new** function bar() in the derived class with a different signature.

So either remove the const in the derived class or add a const to the signature of bar() in the upper class. (Or keep it as it is but know that you now have two functions named bar() in derived class, one of which is hidden)

Comment: Why the call to  `derived_ptr->bar(1.0);` is calling Derived::bar(double) const ?

Comment: Because derived_bar is not `const`.

Comment: @kopiro : because that's the only matching candidate, since the `bar` methods defined in `Base` are hidden because of name hiding.

Comment: @kopiro Because derived_ptr points to an instance of the Derived class which has a function called bar(double) const.

Comment: In my head, base_ptr and derived_ptr are similar things, cause they both points to a `Derived*`, right?

Comment: No, they are not.

Comment: @RoaaGharra: Ok, so why `base_ptr->foo(12.0)` will call `Derived::foo(int)` ?

Comment: because here we have a pointer to Base which points to an instance of Derived. So, what happens is that the compiler searches for foo in Base. It finds it but, it's virtual, so it checks the real type of the instance, it finds that it's Derived so it takes the function foo from Derived.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Instead the `derived_ptr` will check from the Derived class and AFTER to the Base?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133429/discussion-between-kopiro-and-roaagharra).

Comment: Yes, exactly. The compiler always looks for the function in the class that is pointed to. If the function was not found, it searches for it in parent classes.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `const` changes the signature of the function, so they're different. Either make both the base class and derived class `const` or not, otherwise one won't override the other.

Answer (score 2):

C++11 added the [`override` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) to prevent these kind of *surprises*. Use, the `override` keyword, and the compiler will only compile your code, if it does override.

Taking the *supposedly override* of `bar(int)` (this also applies to the `bar(double)`:

```
class Base {
public:
  ....
  virtual void bar(int) { cout << "Base::bar(int)" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  ...
  //This isn't an override, program is well formed
  void bar(int) const { cout << "Derived::bar(int)" << endl; }
};
```

The `bar` member function in `Derived` did not override the base class' own. Because the `const` qualifications are different, hence the member function signatures are different. **All you did in the derived class was to add a new overload and hide that of the base class'**.

Add the `override` keyword in the derived class' and the compiler will give a diagnostic if it doesn't override.

```
class Base {
public:
  ....
  virtual void bar(int) { cout << "Base::bar(int)" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  ...
  //This isn't an override, program is ill-formed, diagnostic required
  void bar(int) const override { cout << "Derived::bar(int)" << endl; }
};
```

To override, the member function signatures must be the same.

```
class Base {
public:
  ....
  virtual void bar(int) { cout << "Base::bar(int)" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  ...
  //This overrides
  void bar(int) override { cout << "Derived::bar(int)" << endl; }
};
```

So, learn to use the override keyword whenever you want to override, it will save you some headaches.

Comment: I'm not understanding why the call to derived_ptr->bar(1.0); is calling Derived::bar(double) const ?
The Base::bar should be called anyway, or not?

Comment: @kopiro : as said elsewhere : the `bar` methods defined in `Base` are hidden because of name hiding, so they are not candidates for the overload resolution.

Comment: @kopiro Here is how it goes. Derived pointer points to an instance of the class Derived. So, when there is a call to any method, the compiler searches the class Derived for a method with the same name. Found one? YES! bar(double) const. So that's the function that is called.